# Spring JdbcTemplate deleting with query() method in Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I'm using `JdbcTemplate` from Spring to query the Oracle DB and return the results. However, if I run the `query()` method with a DELETE statement, it replies with an "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement" error, but the entries are deleted nevertheless.

Is this a Spring bug or an Oracle bug, and how can I fix it? `query()` should not be able to modify.

Comment: Why not use `jdbcTemplate.update` that is specifically designed for SQL insert/update/delete

Comment: Why shouldn't query be able to modify? It just executes a query just as the `update` method does, however the only thing is that it expects a `ResultSet` it can parse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `JdbcTemplate.update` method. It is [meant](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-) for execution a single DML operator(insert/update/delete)

Comment: I don't want to update, I only want to select. the web service where this function is used should only be used to read not to write, despite the role of the user.

Comment: If there is an exception hibernate rolls back the transaction. So entries couldn't be deleted.